# Can flutter adjust desktop brightness

Tags: flutter, desktop-application

I have made research on controlling brightness of the desktop using flutter since it support desktop development but I found nothing helpful, is there any way can we solve this issue

Comment: By desktop do you mean mobile device brightness or PC brightness?

Comment: i mean pc brightness